# Trying to add Image onto JFrame

Tags: java, image, jframe, imageobserver

Hello I'm trying to add an Image that I have on my desktop to my JFrame that I have created i have imported all the necessary functions and the correct variables the only trouble i have is with Image observer I set my x and y values for my image but it causes an error in my drawImage component and it asks for an Image observer which i don't know what it is and if i auto fill something my Image doesn't appear on my JFrame. If one of you can look at my code or answer what an Image observer does i would be greatly appreciated

```
public class Window2 extends JPanel {

    // Image Import 
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("C: / Class Pokemon Game/ src / GameTitle (1).psd"); 
    Image title = i.getImage();


public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(0, 40, 5000, 20);

    g.**drawImage**(title, 500, 500);

}
```

}

the error is
 add argument to match 'drawImage(Image, int, int, ImageObserver)'

Comment: "it causes an error [...] and it asks for an Image observer" - Please edit your question to include the full error message

Answer (score 0):

`ImageObserver` is an interface that has methods for handling notification of state of image loading. It can use this for redisplay as needed.  `JFrame` and `Applet` both implement `ImageObserver` interface.

To keep users informed regarding the loading of *an* image

- `ImageObserver` interface – Enables the monitoring of the loading process so that 
  users can be informed and the image can be used asap once it is loaded.
- Loading an image asynchronously – how to know when the image is ready.

  - An image is ready – `getImage()` method returns, long before anything is 
    known about the image.

    ```
    imageUpdate(Image img, int infoflags, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    ```
- Note: `java.awt.Component` implements `ImageObserver`, all the subclasses do as 
  well!
- `g.drawImage(imge, 0,0, this)` -- this refers to the `ImageObserver` instance.
- `imageUpdate()` – Called by the `ImageObserver` whenever necessary. You do not call 
  it explicitly!

  - If the image is complete, returns `false`.
  - If the image is not complete and needs to be updated, returns `true`.
- `ImageObserver.ALLBITS = 32`
- Various constants are combined to form the `infoflags` argument, which indicates 
  whether all information is available or not.

  [image: info flag table]

Answer (score 0):

You can skip using an ImageObserver by putting it as null
for example (Using Graphics2D)

```
g2.drawImage(Image texture, x, y, width, height, null);
```